# UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification working for iDevice 4 and under but not iDevice 5

Tags: iphone, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation, ipod-touch

Dudes!

Need some urgent insight.
My problem is that even though tests on iPhone 4/4S and iPod 4 rotate normally with this code here:

```
- (void)initNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"setFreeOrientation" object:nil];

    [[UIDevice currentDevice]beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                            selector:@selector(didRotate:)
                                                name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
                                              object:Nil];
}

-(void)didRotate:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    [super rotateTopBars];
    [super rotateOptionsBar];
    [self rotateControlBar];
    [self rotatePlayer];
    [super rotateShareLayer];
}
```

but i'm testing on a iPod 5 and it doesn't work.
tried some stuff but no luck till now.

cheers.

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3821151/uideviceorientationdidchangenotification-not-firing), its almost exactly the same problem as yours, I believe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had a similar issue with `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification`, where it worked fine on one device, but not another. After a bit of debugging I realised that I had Portrait Orientation Locked on the device, and this was causing the `UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification` to not fire at all. Not sure if that's your issue, but it's something that's easy to overlook and worth checking.

[image: Portrait Orientation Locked]

Comment: I guess I use my entire life for looking the invisible bug... Thanks for the help!

Comment: Is there any way to unlock this through programmatically?

Comment: That was my problem too.  Did not realize that the orientation on the device was locked ages ago.  (Test device).  Thanks!